# DataSet related issues when using ReportVIewer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting, reportviewer

I'm new to reporting in VS 2010 and I'm trying to use integrated report viewer. My current understanding is that If my system has 10 reports I should create 10 `DataSet`s so one `DataSet` per report. The problem is I want to organize these `DataSet`s in the IDE. I have folders for each type of reports in the solution explorer and I want to move respective `DataSet`s to such forlders.

But when it is moved to a folder list of errors are shown in the code and after realizing that the namespace names of the moved `DataSet`s have been changed, I manually changed them to original namespaces but still I have problems like `System.DataSet1DataAdapter` not found, No fill method have been defined etc etc.

How to solve this problem? Otherwise is it better to keep `DataSets` in the root folder?

Could we create DataSets for reports in code? What is the practice in professional level?

Is integrated reporting considered a consistent way to do reporting?

**NOT:** I'm developing a Win forms application

Comment: You can use shared datasets if there are multiple reports using same data structures. I think better to create dataset in the right place at the beginning of report creation otherwise you should find and fix all changes in namespaces.

Comment: @Grievoushead, Even I create ds inside the right folder, the ds is not available to report (Report also in the same folder). If the ds in root then only its available. What'd you mean by same data structures?  In my case database is same and different table joins will be used by reports.